# Maui FlyoutFooter in iOS not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, xaml, maui

[image]I just want to implement a footer in my Flyout for Android and iOS.
Here's my code for my AppShell Footer
`.

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <VerticalStackLayout IgnoreSafeArea="False">
                <Label Text="Footer" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                <Label Text="Footer2" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                <Label Text="Text" TextColor="Red"></Label>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>`
```

If i display this the last Text it is directly over the safe Area of iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue that the last text gets covered by the safe area on **iOS**.

As an alternative workaround, you can try to set `HeightRequest` of the `StackLayout` like below:

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate> 
      <DataTemplate>
             <StackLayout>
                  <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                         <On Platform="iOS" Value="80"/>
                     </OnPlatform>
                   </StackLayout.HeightRequest>

                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Footer" TextColor="Red"/>
                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Footer" TextColor="Red"/>
                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Footer" TextColor="Red"/>


              </StackLayout>
       </DataTemplate>

</Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Okay so im not alone :D, why the Value of 80 ? Is there a possibility to get the exact Value of the Safe Area?

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for the update, since you have three labels, set the value to 80 exactly help avoid displaying over the safe area.